# WordPress ajax call custom query_vars

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have plugin which responds to an ajax call but when I try to retrive list of query vars the list is empty.

This is the request:

```
http://www.xxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?minutes=1500&data=1&action=get_cbp_contracts
```

in the ajax action I have

```
class Contracts
{
    [...]

    /**
     * query params
     *
     * @var array
     */
     public static $query_params = array(        
        'minutes' => 'minutes', 
        'data' => 'data'        
    );

    function get_contracts(){
        foreach (Contracts::$query_params as $name => $api_name)
            if ($value = get_query_var($name))
                $p = $value;

    }

    [...]
}

function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  foreach (array_keys(Contracts::$query_params) as $name)
    $vars[] = $name;
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

After a bit of investigation I know that add_query_vars_filter() is never executed. Any idea?

EDIT:
js code

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: form.serialize().replace(/[^&]+=\.?(?:&|$)/g, ''),
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(result) {
                [...]
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                [...]
            }
        })
```

Comment: This code is in custom plugin of yours, or you put this in functions.php? Be sure that there is only one functions.php. Sometimes, there may be custom functions.php for themes

Comment: It's in a custom plugin the Contract class & add_query_vars_filter function in the same file

Comment: You sure about that, it is not entering `add_query_vars_filter` right?

Comment: yes I've put die('test') inside of this function so I would see in the client

Comment: You didn't see "tes" right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49139/discussion-between-huseyin-babal-and-arek-s)

Answer (score 1):

Arek, I feel you should try to change the datatype and test it with html.

change

```
 dataType: 'json',
```

to

```
 dataType: 'html',
```

Comment: I'm giving up on this. Will use $_REQUEST insteed. Thanks for help anyway Ram

Comment: Arek, still I feel that you should test one more time type:"POST" instead of GET and don't use any dataType: beacuse you are passing JSON data. it's just suggestion rest is depends on you.